# Perl search / replace with capture group on CLI

Tags: regex, perl

PHP's `strlen()` function is not UTF-8 aware, so I would like to swap each usage of `strlen()` with its UTF-8 aware counterpart: `mb_strlen()`. However, `mb_strlen()` requires an additional argument:

```
$length = strlen($someString);
$length = mb_strlen($someString, 'UTF-8');
```

Had there not been a second argument, a simple Perl regex would handle the swap:

```
$ find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/strlen/mb_strlen/g'
```

I tried using capture groups and backreferences but the VIM-style syntax either does not support that (on a recent Ubuntu) or I cannot figure it out. I've tried several variations on this without success:

```
$ find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/strlen\((\.*)\)/mb_strlen\($1, "UTF-8"\)/g'
```

Furthermore, there may be functions such as `trim()` inside `strlen()` so I would have to make this greedy but I'm not sure where the greedy operator should go exactly. How should this regex be written?

Answer (score 1):

This is more difficult than it first appears. You either need to:

1. Parse the expression properly, including multi-line versions of the expression.
2. Cheat

I'd go for cheat.

Most of the strlen() calls will be quite simple, the handful that are left can be manually replaced. And you're doing this under some sort of version-control, aren't you:

Simple: strlen("foo"), strlen($bar)

```
# Match simple quoted strings - no embedded quotes
s/strlen\((["'][^"']*["'])\)/mb_strlen($1, 'UTF-8')/g
# Match simple variables - no method calls etc
s/strlen\((\$\w+)\)/mb_strlen($1, 'UTF-8')/g
```

Handling array-variables, function and method calls and other expressions gets more complicated, but see how many are left after these two basic replacements.

Comment: Why not just use `[^()]*` to match inside the function?  This would be pretty safe and would capture those two cases and more.

Comment: Breaks on strlen(')') - I said it was more difficult than it appears :-)

Comment: how much code really takes the length of a string literal?  I don't think I have ever done that.  And even out of that, literals containing a close parenthesis would be a tiny subset.  Your point is taken, but that is a failure case I would be willing to live with when doing a search and replace on code.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `\.*`, the regex will match 0 or more literal `'.'`s.

Try it after omitting the `\`:

```
s/strlen\((.*)\)/mb_strlen($1, "UTF-8")/g
           ^              ^           ^
           NO BACKSLASH   NO BACKSLASH NEEDED
                          AS THIS IS TREATED AS
                          A STRING AND NOT A REGEX
```

Also, try testing it without the `-i` flag first to make sure you're happy with the substitution, else your files will be modified in-situ.

Comment: This will break if you have any other bracketed expressions on the same line.

Comment: @RichardHuxton : Of course it'll break for anything but the most simple of cases. My intention was to show what was wrong with the OP's regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not solvable in the general case with a simple regex.  Consider these examples:

```
if (strlen($var) > 0)

$total_length = strlen($thing1) + strlen($thing2);

strlen($var);   #Don't use trim() here because it was already trimmed.

some_other_function(strlen($foo) + 2);
```

None of these would work with your regex, because `.*` will greedily capture everything up until the last close parenthesis in the line.  The only way to do this correctly is check for balanced parentheses, which is non-trivial in a regex (though it is technically possible with Perl's extended regex features, it would be no easy task).

If you don't think you'll run into very many of the cases above, then just use one of the other suggested solutions and check for errors. Or you could do this to catch all of the simple cases that don't have any parentheses within them:

```
s/\bstrlen\(([^()]*)\)/mb_strlen($1, "UTF-8")/g
```

(Note, I also added `\b` to make sure it starts at a word boundary.  This will stop you from double-replacing  things that are already `mb_strlen`)

However, there is an easy quick hack solution that should work for *all cases*: create your own PHP function called `my_mb_strlen`, or whatever, that calls `mb_strlen` while adding the additional argument.  Then you can perform a much simpler search and replace for the function name only, replacing `strlen` with `my_mb_strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f|xargs perl -pi -e 's/strlen\(([^\)]*)\)/mb_strlen($1,'UTF_8')/g'
```